# Activity not closing on Back press when theme is Theme.NoDisplay

Tags: android, android-activity

I am setting Activity Theme to `Theme.NoDisplay` but When it open but on press back button Activity not closing/destroying. It should close/destroy on back press.

Guys help me why this is so and any solution to resolve this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Tag of the Activity
    private static String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DatabaseManager.init(this);

        NFCIItem mNFCItem = new NFCIItem();
        mNFCItem.setSerialNumber(1);

        DatabaseManager.getInstance().addWishList(mNFCItem);
        final List<NFCIItem> wishLists = DatabaseManager.getInstance().getAllNFCSerialNumber();
        Log.v(TAG, wishLists.toString());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.appdemo.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I imagine it is closing but you see no evidence of this because it is 'NoDisplay'. Do 2 back presses do as you expect? And why use a NoDisplay Activity that does not finish() in onCreate? If it has no visible UI, you shouldn't keep it alive. Can you explain what UI / workflow you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: @NigelK As I know to scan the NFC Tag, you have to make the activity. In our case there is no views on the activity. So I thought to make it invisible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine it is closing but you see no evidence of this because it is 'NoDisplay'. An Activity using this theme has no visible UI (hence it is not logical for such an Activity to process UI events) and should not be kept alive. See this question for example:

[how to completely get rid of an activity's GUI (avoid a black screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551868)

If you do want this Activity's layout to be visible and to handle events, you should use a different theme. If on the otherhand this is an invisible Activity that just does some background processing, call finish() in onCreate to close it when that processing is done.

Answer (score -2):

You can override the back button event to manually close the activity

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        YourActivity.this.finish();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I debug the application, this method not executing on setting the Theme to Theme.NoDisplay

Answer (score -3):

You can override the back button to launch the main activity and instantly close it without animation. This will appear as a single action to the user.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,
            R.anim.slide_out_right);
}
```

Comment: I debug the application, this method not executing on setting the Theme to Theme.NoDisplay